# Stop listening port 1099 from wildfly 10.1

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi

Does anyone know how we can stop Listening TCP port 1099 from wildfly.

I tried to remove remote-naming service(removed ) since it is not using my application. But it is still showing listening to port 1099 once I start wildfly.

Can we bind naming service to using different port or does anyone know how to stop listening to a port 1099 in Java?

Comment: Version of WildFly?

Comment: Wildfly version is 10.1

Comment: It only listens on ports 8080, 9990 by default and 8443 for https if enabled by default, you must have none standard config file or part of your deployment. Can you share your standalone config and does the port still listen when you have no app deployed?

Comment: Thanks @WillT for your reply. Actually this port not opening when I start wildfly without my app. But my app doesn't required any remote-naming service or remote JNDI lookup. So is there anyway I can stop those services?

Comment: You can just remove the section of the standalone file you are running with that relates to that connector. I don't have the xml to hand right now, but message back if you need more specific instructions

Comment: I removed '<remote-naming/>' from standalone config. But still it is listening to the port 1099.

Comment: @WillT Do you have sample standalone config to remove remote JNDI lookup? It will be great help to fix this vulnerability issue.

Comment: If your app does not use websocket at all, it might be better you run apache+mod_proxy, haproxy or nginx in front of wildfly and only proxy the urls you need rather than exposing wildfly to the world directly. That way you can protect the appserver from many attscks as they simply can't get that far.  To ease the transition, you can just swap wildfly to bind to 127.0.0.1 and then set the proxy to listen on the ip previously bound to wildfly. This greatly reduces the attack surface and also establishes a structure that allows you to run a ha profile later if you want to start clustering

Comment: thanks again @WillT for your comment. I able to figure out jmx service inside my application using port 1099 (jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi) I need to find a way to configure it to use different port.